# get and post with php not working properly

Tags: php

I am new at php. I am using a wamp server and I created two php pages in the www directory.
One is index.php with the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action = "formprocess.php" method = "post">
            Your name : <input type = "text" name = "name"> <br>
            <input type = "submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and another formprocess.php with the code below:

```
<?php
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        echo "your name is " . $name;
?>
```

Whenever I try to submit the form, it just displays the entire formprocess.php code as it is in the browser. It does not matter also if I use the get method. Please tell me where am I going wrong.

Comment: To run PHP code, your webserver needs the module installed first or at the very least being configured properly.

Comment: Can you post some output? like a screenshot?

Comment: ... assuming, of course, that the OP is accessing the file via `http` and *not* just opening it in a browser. @Xorifelse

Comment: what errors?? its working fine on my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See link, there basic first steps for run php code. I hope, this will help!
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/run-a-php-program-in-xampp-server

Comment: I remember , though I am using a wampserver, it is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok and runs properly on my side.

If you can see your PHP Code in the browser, your webserver probably doesn't know how to interpret PHP code.

Ensure that your webserver supports PHP and it is installed.

You can simple test it with a small "Hello World"-Page which just echoes a text (just to ensure that the error is not in your script)

```
<?php
    echo "Test";
?>
```

should just display "Test" in your browser. The Php-tags should not be visible!

edit:
**Also important to note:** You have to access your files through the webserver with http://localhost/yourfile.php and not with your local path-to-your-file like <strike>C:/wwwroot/yourfile.php</strike>. The latter won't get executed by your webserver and therefor no php-code gets executed.

Comment: Indeed it is outputting the the entire code. But I do not understand it didn't happened before. I have successfully installed wamp and it is running servers perfectly (that little green icon the traybar).

Answer (score 0):

Just found out in order to run your php code from wampserver, you need to type the url in the browser. Like in my case it is localhost/form.php and when I pressed entered it worked along with formprocess.php perfectly. Thanks for all your efforts.